# Chart.js not displaying Django Rest API data

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, chart.js

I have REST API with django rest framework like this :

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-04T11:46:10+07:00",
    "vibration": 3,
    "moisture": 70,
    "gps_latitude": "-7.760776",
    "gps_longitude": "110.376113",
    "gyro_x": 6.58,
    "gyro_y": 85.0,
    "gyro_z": -3.9,
    "accelero_x": 6.58,
    "accelero_y": 85.0,
    "accelero_z": -3.9,
    "displacement": 10,
    "node_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-05T11:46:10+07:00",
    "vibration": 4,
    "moisture": 40,
    "gps_latitude": "-5.760776",
    "gps_longitude": "115.376113",
    "gyro_x": 5.58,
    "gyro_y": 55.0,
    "gyro_z": -5.9,
    "accelero_x": 5.58,
    "accelero_y": 55.0,
    "accelero_z": -5.9,
    "displacement": 50,
    "node_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "timestamp": "2020-03-12T11:46:10+07:00",
    "vibration": 8,
    "moisture": 90,
    "gps_latitude": "-5.769776",
    "gps_longitude": "125.376113",
    "gyro_x": 7.58,
    "gyro_y": 65.0,
    "gyro_z": -9.9,
    "accelero_x": 4.58,
    "accelero_y": 45.0,
    "accelero_z": -4.9,
    "displacement": 40,
    "node_id": 2
}]
```

And this is the code for making rest API :

```
models.py from app directory

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Data(models.Model):
   node_id = models.ForeignKey("Node", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
   vibration = models.IntegerField()
   moisture = models.IntegerField()
   gps_latitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   gps_longitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   gyro_x = models.FloatField()
   gyro_y = models.FloatField()
   gyro_z = models.FloatField()
   accelero_x = models.FloatField()
   accelero_y = models.FloatField()
   accelero_z = models.FloatField()
   displacement = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.node_id

class Node(models.Model):
     node_id = models.IntegerField()
```

This is serializers.py from app directory :

```
serializers.py

from .models import Data,Node
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  id = serializers.IntegerField()
  username = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
  password = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, style={"input_type":"password"})
  is_staff = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)

def create(self, validated_data):
    """The function called when you create a new User object/instance"""

    return User.objects.create(**validated_data)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    """
    Update and return an existing `User` instance, given the validated data.
    """
    instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
    instance.password = validated_data.get('password', instance.password)
    instance.is_staff = validated_data.get('is_staff', instance.is_staff)
    instance.save()
    return instance

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'is_staff')


class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Data
    fields = '__all__'


class NodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta :
    model = Node
    fields = '__all__'
```

This is views.py from app directory :

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from restapi.serializers import UserSerializer, DataSerializer, NodeSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from restapi.models import Data, Node
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

class Charts(View):
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'charts.html')


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = User.objects.all()
 serializer_class = UserSerializer


class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Data.objects.all()
 serializer_class = DataSerializer
 filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
 filterset_fields = ['node_id']


class NodeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Node.objects.all()
 serializer_class = NodeSerializer
```

And this is urls.py from project directory :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from restapi import views

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from restapi.models import Data, Node
from rest_framework import routers

from restapi.views import UserViewSet, DataViewSet, NodeViewSet, Charts


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api/users', UserViewSet)

router.register(r'api/data', DataViewSet)

router.register(r'api/node', NodeViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path(r'', include(router.urls)),
  path(r'api/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
  path('charts/', Charts.as_view(), name='charts'),
]
```

And this is the code for chart.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
  $("#firstdatepicker").datepicker();
  $("#lastdatepicker").datepicker();
  $("#filter").click(function() {
    var from_date = $("#firstdatepicker").val();
    var to_date = $("#lastdatepicker").val();
    if (from_date != '' && to_date != '') {
      console.log(from_date, to_date);
      var endpoint = '/api/data'
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: endpoint,
    data: {
      from_date: from_date,
      to_date: to_date
    },
    success: function(data){

      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
              labels: data.timestamp,
              datasets: [{
                  label: 'moisture',
                  data: data.moisture,
                  backgroundColor: [
                      'rgb(68, 145, 252)'
                  ],
                  borderColor: [
                  '#331698'
                  ],
                  borderCapStyle: 'round',
                  borderWidth: 1
              }]
          },
          options: {
              reponsive: true,
              scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                          beginAtZero:true,
                          max:100,
                          stepSize:10
                      },
                        scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'moisture'
                    }
                  }],
                  xAxes: [{
                          display: true,
                          ticks: {
                            min: from_date,
                            max: to_date,
                          },
                          type: 'time',
                          time: {
                            displayFormats: {
                              second: 'h:mm:ss a'
                            }
                          },
                        scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'Date'
                    }
                  }]
              }
          }
      });
    },
    error: function(error_data){
      console.log(error_data)
    }
  });
} else {
  alert("Please Select Date");
}
  });    })
```

pip list :

```
jango-filter       2.2.0
djangorestframework 3.11.0
get                 2019.4.13
pip                 20.0.2
post                2019.4.13
psycopg2            2.8.4
public              2019.4.13
pytz                2019.3
query-string        2019.4.13
request             2019.4.13
setuptools          40.8.0
sqlparse            0.3.1
```

I don't know what's wrong. The data can't be display on chart. I am new with django. I am using django 2.2.5

[no display data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npmOU.png)

I really appreciate you guys if you want to help me. I am sorry my English is so bad, i am not a native.

Comment: Did you try to track this down step by step? I would try to figure out whether the correct data was generated at the API level first (some plain and simple logging helps a great way) and eventually just print out the json data in the front end (as text on the page, actually). Maybe this sounds plain and boring, but it might just help in pinning down what might get lost along the way.

Comment: i want my API can be used for method "get" and "post". so  i try to follow some tutorials in the internet. i already test my API with the "post" and "get" method using postman and it's works.  And then i want the data on my API can be plot on the chart.js using the API url endpoint as the data source. But i think there is some mistake while doing it, but it doesn't give an error on the terminal so i can't figure it out where is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

At the code for chart.js, try to change url `endpoint` to `http address`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
  $("#firstdatepicker").datepicker();
  $("#lastdatepicker").datepicker();
  $("#filter").click(function() {
    var from_date = $("#firstdatepicker").val();
    var to_date = $("#lastdatepicker").val();
    if (from_date != '' && to_date != '') {
      console.log(from_date, to_date);
      var endpoint = '/api/data'
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://your-server:port/api/data/",
    data: {
      from_date: from_date,
      to_date: to_date
    },
    success: function(data){
      //check the data, if it's already return the correct array mentioned at the beginning of the question
      console.log(data);

      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
              labels: data.timestamp,
              datasets: [{
                  label: 'moisture',
                  data: data.moisture,
                  backgroundColor: [
                      'rgb(68, 145, 252)'
                  ],
                  borderColor: [
                  '#331698'
                  ],
                  borderCapStyle: 'round',
                  borderWidth: 1
              }]
          },
          options: {
              reponsive: true,
              scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                          beginAtZero:true,
                          max:100,
                          stepSize:10
                      },
                        scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'moisture'
                    }
                  }],
                  xAxes: [{
                          display: true,
                          ticks: {
                            min: from_date,
                            max: to_date,
                          },
                          type: 'time',
                          time: {
                            displayFormats: {
                              second: 'h:mm:ss a'
                            }
                          },
                        scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'Date'
                    }
                  }]
              }
          }
      });
    },
    error: function(error_data){
      console.log(error_data)
    }
  });
} else {
  alert("Please Select Date");
}
  });    })
```